# BeautifulSoup и аргумент text выводит пустую строку хотя без него данные что я ищу есть

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, discord.py

Страница которую я пращу https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Sipmlne
вчера писал для бота команду что бы тот парсил сайт и получал статистику игрока. Див который мне нужен имеет data- и класс trn-defstats

эту часть я хочу вывести точнее WINS и LOSSES
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код

```
URL = None
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36'}

@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx, nick):
    global URL
    website = 'https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/'
    URL = website + nick

    def get_html(url):
        global HEADERS

        r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        return r
    def get_content(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('div', class_='trn-text--dimmed')
        img = soup.find('div', class_='trn-profile-header__avatar').find('img')
        
        wins = soup.find(attrs={'data-stat': 'PVPMatchesWon'}).text #тут у меня проблема почему то выводит пустую строку
        ranks = []

        for item in items:
            title = item.get_text(strip=True)
            ranks.append({
                'title': title,
            })

        MMR = ranks[1]['title']
        TRANK = ranks[0]['title']
        print(MMR)
        print(TRANK)
        print(wins)
        return MMR, TRANK, img['src'], RANK_IMG[TRANK]

    def parse():
        global URL
        html = get_html(URL)
        if html.status_code == 200:
            print('Connect to website')
            mmr_rank = get_content(html.text)
            return mmr_rank

        else:
            print('Error')
библиотеки 

    import discord
    from discord.ext import tasks, commands
    from config import settings
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
```

Answer (score 0):

*Не используйте `requests` в асинхронном коде. `requests` [блокирует выполнение асинхронного кода](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code). Старайтесь по возможности использовать асинхронные библиотеки. Например, [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/).*

Учитывая вышесказанное, в данном случае вижу вариант проще - использовать [`ruia`](https://docs.python-ruia.org):

````py
from ruia import Item, TextField
from tabulate import tabulate  # https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/


class TrackerStat(Item):
    target_item = TextField(css_select=".trn-defstat")
    name = TextField(css_select=".trn-defstat__name")
    value = TextField(css_select=".trn-defstat__value")

    async def clean_name(self, value):
        return value.strip()

    async def clean_value(self, value):
        return value.strip()


@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx, nick: str):
    table = tabulate(
        {
            item.name: item.value
            async for item in TrackerStat.get_items(
                url=f"https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/{nick}"
            )
        }.items()
    )
    await ctx.send(f"```\n{table}\n```")
````

Comment: Спасибо. Я забыл дописать что когда я просто вожу без .text все нормально выводить.